# Magnolia instance not starting

Tags: magnolia

[image: i tryed to start magnolia after jumpstart to the version 6.2.3]
i tryed solution like  changing the host file and adding java_home in environment
mgnl jumpstart -m version was 6.2.3
then I tryed to start magnolia instance without created the module

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Maven was not correctly installed

Step 1: Download Maven https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip

Step 2: unzip it and add to environment variables as
M2_HOME  - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3
MAVEN_HOME - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3
AND in path add its bin C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin